# Enable plugin only on certain folder (Eclipse RCP)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, plugin.xml

I created a simple Eclipse plugin, to launch a wizard and create some files, everything is working, I also added an option lo launch the wizard from the `New > Mi Wizard` menu, but now I want to display this option only when I right click an specific folder in a project, this is what I have so far:

This is my wizard:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
    <category
        name="My Category"
        id="com.test.myCategory">
    </category>
    <wizard
        name="My Wizard"
        icon="icons/wizard1.gif"
        category="com.test.myCategory"
        class="com.test.myWizard"
        id="com.test.myWizard">
    </wizard>
</extension>
```

And this is how I'm adding the wizard to the `New` menu:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
    <commonWizard 
        type="new" 
        wizardId="com.test.myWizard"
        menuGroupId="testGroup">
        <enablement>
            <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder">
                <test property="org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.projectFacet" value="myFacet:1.3" forcePluginActivation="true"/>
            </adapt>
        </enablement>
    </commonWizard>
</extension>
```

The option in the `New` menu is displayed correctly, but it is displayed when I right click all folders, is there a way to display the option only when I right click a certain folder, specifically the `WebContent` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `org.eclipse.core.resources.name` property tester to test the resource name:

```xml
<adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder">
  <and>
    <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="WebContent"/>
    <test property="org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.projectFacet" value="myFacet:1.3" forcePluginActivation="true"/>
  </and>
</adapt>
```